# What are the benefits using terminal multiplexer

Tags: tmux, terminal-multiplexer

I am using terminal, vim, mutt, etc daily. I use windows, tabs and panes. Now I came to know about Tmux, terminal-multiplexer. But I am not quite sure why I need to use it. I already using windows and panes which Tmux is talking about.

Can anyone give me good reason(s) why or when I should use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between multiplexing using tmux/screen and opening tabs in a terminal emulator?](https://superuser.com/questions/1378470/what-are-the-differences-between-multiplexing-using-tmux-screen-and-opening-tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tmux (and the older *screen*) allow one terminal session (eg. ssh connection) to act like many sessions.  The panes allows sections of the terminal screen to be divided among sessions, much like windows (Mac/Win/X11.)

The most valuable feature is the ability to disconnect, and reconnect to a session, and even connect to the same session multiple times (ie. from one than one location.)

Comment: You mean that if you are using ssh, then it is a good idea. Otherwise not.

Comment: I use it even when I have a windowed environment -- so I can reconnect to my sessions.

Comment: @RickyBeam: But do you use it for local windows, those that aren't connected to sessions? Personally, I don't like using `tmux` locally because scrolling is awkward, but the split-window feature can be useful even locally for editing a program in one window and running it in another because jumping between `tmux` windows is so easy. For ssh sessions, `tmux` is great, for the reasons you gave.

Comment: Running local commands in tmux can be nice. If you are someone who uses/likes the terminator terminal emulator, tmux makes it unnecessary. And another nice thing about using it locally, is you can then connect remotely from other computers/servers to your local instance. @garyjohn: For your awkward scrolling, are you using mouse mode? I find tmux scrolling is great (both with mouse, and keyboard)

Comment: @demure: No, I hadn't tried mode-mouse. It seems to work pretty well. I'd prefer something like Shift-Up and Shift-Down because that's what my fingers are used to, but I'll give mode-mouse a try. Thanks.